# How can I add a csrf token on a http request in python?

Tags: python, django, http, http-headers, django-csrf

I am using Django 1.4 to build a web service. My intention is to use it just as a web server (no browser involved), which means there's no form or template involved in the http request. I plan to use AJAX in the future but for now the client is just making requests using Python's request library. I'm getting the «CSRF verification failed. Request aborted» error. The documentation says I'm supposed to «add a CSRF token» to each http request when trying to POST, but I have no idea what this means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827079/django-csrf-token-without-forms) answer, and [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) documentation page.

In short: Add a `X-CSRFToken` header in your `POST` request that holds the token.

Comment: I did, but the documentation does not help at all if you're not using Jquery (They just say add a CSRF token like I should know what that means), and the answer just points to the documentation page.

Comment: @Sofia Bravo: how are you making POST requests to your django webserver endpoint now?

Comment: Simply by doing: `import requests`
`url = "http://..."`           
`answer = requests.post(url)`

Comment: @SofiaBravo I think RickyA is asking about the ajax call in your template, how does it look like?

Comment: @Sofia Bravo: If you are calling your post method from code you don't need crfs protection. This security is to prevent hijacking of a [**link on a website**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). You do probably want user/api authentication, but that is something else.

Comment: @dan-klasson: not js framework or html page is used. The POST request is done directly from python code running serverside.

Comment: If you're not using any session based authentication, then just disable the csrf protection. There is a decorator called `@csrf_excempt` or something like that.

Comment: I disabled CSRF authorization (using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650941/django-csrf-framework-cannot-be-disabled-and-is-breaking-my-site)) since it was not necessary, thanks.