# iPhone POSTing to Django and gets CSRF verification failed

Tags: iphone, django, post, django-csrf

I send a POST request from IPhone to Django and get "CSRF verification failed", which I can't perfectly understand.
I tried to find a good solution over the internet, but I couldn't .
is there any simple way to POST to django?

this is my code:

```
   NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"s=aaa&r=k&c=gg"];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:(@"http://localhost:8000/messages/views/")]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(data);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally this boils down to setting the headers correctly. There is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5107878/991521) that already details this. The relevant part you need is this:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", token)
```

See the linked answer for details on getting the token from the cookies, for brevity I didn't copy it from there. I don't really know the context of your code, so this method of retrieval might not directly apply. Regardless, you need to get the token somehow.

When you have the token, add a header to the `NSMutableURLRequest`. Upon posting the request, the error should be gone.

```
[request addValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-CSRFToken"];
```

Comment: I still have no idea how to get the token

Comment: Well, the idea with CSRF tokens is that the server has to generate them for you. This means that you cannot POST without receiving a token (via a GET) first. If you want to do this without the GET... that's a bit of an issue, since it would make the entire protection mechanism obsolete. You might be able to create a static token, but then you'll have a problem when someone else figures it out. So... I think you need to determine how (or better, if) you need the protection to be done.

Comment: so how do I receive the token via GET?

Comment: See the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) on this. Mainly, you render a view to a template. Within that template, use the `{% csrf_token %}` tag. Upon receiving that page in your GET, extract the token, and reuse it in your POST.

Answer (score 7):

Am I wrong or it just don't make sense to use this on native app?

In that case, you could just disable this protection using this decorator:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
  def view_without_csrf_protection(request):
    pass
```

Comment: Suggesting to not use a CSRF on the view is a workaround that can cause a security problem. It s not a solution for the problem