# Iphone posting to django web server gives csrf verification error

Tags: iphone, ios, django

I am trying to create an iphone app which will do a validation of the user's login.

However when i passed in the username and password, and prints a log of the jsonString that it receives from the web,

**I get the following error:**

```
2012-01-11 13:44:51.470 Different Views[53942:18903] 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
  <title>403 Forbidden</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
    body * { padding:10px 20px; }
    body * * { padding:0; }
    body { font:small sans-serif; background:#eee; }
    body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }
    h1 { font-weight:normal; margin-bottom:.4em; }
    h1 span { font-size:60; color:#666; font-weight:normal; }
    #info { background:#f6f6f6; }
    #info ul { margin: 0.5em 4em; }
    #info p, #summary p { padding-top:10px; }
    #summary { background: #ffc; }
    #explanation { background:#eee; border-bottom: 0px none; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="summary">
  <h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1>
  <p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>

</div>

<div id="info">
  <h2>Help</h2>

    <p>Reason given for failure:</p>
    <pre>
    CSRF token missing or incorrect.
    </pre>


  <p>In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when
  <a
  href='http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ref-contrib-csrf'>Django's
  CSRF mechanism</a> has not been used correctly.  For POST forms, you need to
  ensure:</p>

  <ul>
    <li>The view function uses <a
    href='http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext'><code>RequestContext</code></a>
    for the template, instead of <code>Context</code>.</li>

    <li>In the template, there is a <code>{Jsrf_token
    }</code> template tag inside each POST form that
    targets an internal URL.</li>

    <li>If you are not using <code>CsrfViewMiddleware</code>, then you must use
    <code>csrf_protect</code> on any views that use the <code>csrf_token</code>
    template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.</li>

  </ul>

  <p>You're seeing the help section of this page because you have <code>DEBUG =
  True</code> in your Django settings file. Change that to <code>False</code>,
  and only the initial error message will be displayed.  </p>

  <p>You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This error comes from the webpage that i'm trying to access from.

Based on my own research, i've found a similar ans [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487542/iphone-posting-to-django-and-gets-csrf-verification-failed) but i have no idea how to set/get the token

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: is this in a web view (viewing html and submitting a form) or are you just posting data directly to some (django) view?

Comment: I think from a webview, because otherwise he could have implemented the supplied answer.

Comment: @Stanwin If you call this url from a webview, do you post it from a form or did you put it in a <a href"bla">bla</a> ?

Comment: The error above is generated from my xcode. I got it while trying to Log a variable. It's generated when my application calls the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Django CSRF docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) under "How it Works":

> The CSRF protection is based on the following things:
>
> 1. A CSRF cookie that is set to a random value (a session independent
>      nonce, as it is called), which other sites will not have access to.
>
>    This cookie is set by CsrfViewMiddleware. It is meant to be permanent,
>      but since there is no way to set a cookie that never expires, it is
>      sent with every response that has called
>      django.middleware.csrf.get_token() (the function used internally to
>      retrieve the CSRF token).
> 2. A hidden form field with the name 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' present in all
>      outgoing POST forms. The value of this field is the value of the CSRF
>      cookie.
>
>    This part is done by the template tag.
> 3. For all incoming requests that are not using HTTP GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
>      or TRACE, a CSRF cookie must be present, and the 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'
>      field must be present and correct. If it isn't, the user will get a
>      403 error.
>
>    This check is done by CsrfViewMiddleware.
> 4. In addition, for HTTPS requests, strict referer checking is done by
>      CsrfViewMiddleware. This is necessary to address a Man-In-The-Middle
>      attack that is possible under HTTPS when using a session independent
>      nonce, due to the fact that HTTP 'Set-Cookie' headers are
>      (unfortunately) accepted by clients that are talking to a site under
>      HTTPS. (Referer checking is not done for HTTP requests because the
>      presence of the Referer header is not reliable enough under HTTP.)
>
> *This ensures that only forms that have originated from your Web site
>   can be used to POST data back.* (emphasis mine)

You cannot simply post the username and password, you must also include the CSRF token in the POST data. Take some time to read the docs and understand how CSRF works.

Comment: Sure thing Chris. I'll take some time to understand that CSRF component. Thanks for replying!

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm facing the same problem