# jquery ajax file upload with Django

Tags: jquery, python, django, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery ajaxfileupload plugin http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/
to upload images with Django in server-side. I've also done the ajax setup which I saw here [Django CSRF check failing with an Ajax POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request)
But still I'm getting 403 Forbidden: csrf verification failed.

Here is the client side script:
http://jsfiddle.net/rkumarnirmal/FSDPH/

Here is the Django code:

```
def backgroundview(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        b = request.POST.get('fileToUpload')        
        try:
            g = BackgroundModel.objects.get(user=request.user)
        except CoverModel.DoesNotExist:
            bm = BackgroundModel(background=b)
            bm.user = request.user
            bm.save()
        else:
            g.background = b
            g.save()
        return HttpResponse("")
```

Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you adding the {% csrf_token %} to the rendered form?

Comment: I've tried adding the tag but still getting the same 403 forbidden error

Comment: Can you use alert(getCookie('csrftoken')) to check if you have it set?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use `RequestContext` in your views.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it

Comment: I'm using ajax method so I've included the code I've seen here https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2011/feb/08/security/

Answer (score 0):

Attach the annotation `@csrf_protect` at the top of the view method!