# csrf with ajax and django post

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-csrf

Using jquery1.7.1 and django1.3 ,I was trying to make a post request through ajax,in some tutorial code I found on [web](http://lethain.com/intro-to-unintrusive-javascript-with-django/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#create").click(create_note);

});

var create_note = function() {
  var title = $("#title").val()
  var slug = $("#slug").val()
  if (title != "" && slug != "") {
    var data = { title:title, slug:slug };
    console.log('title='+title);
    console.log('slug='+slug);
    var args = { type:"POST", url:"/create/", data:data, complete:done };
    $.ajax(args);
  }
  else {
    // display failure
  }
  return false;
};
```

The url "/create/" is mapped to django view

```
(r'^create/$','notes.views.create_note'),

def create_note(request):
    error_msg = u"No POST data sent."
    if request.method == "POST":
        post = request.POST.copy()
        if post.has_key('slug') and post.has_key('title'):
            slug = post['slug']
            if Note.objects.filter(slug=slug).count() > 0:
                error_msg = u"Slug already in use."
            else:
                title = post['title']
                new_note = Note.objects.create(title=title,slug=slug)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(new_note.get_absolute_url())
        else:
            error_msg = u"Insufficient POST data (need 'slug' and 'title'!)"
    return HttpResponseServerError(error_msg)
```

When I click the submit button,which triggers the  javascript function `create_note` ,I get a 403 error. Must be the csrf problem..

I tried to solve this by modifying the ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
        data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },
    });
        $("#create").click(create_note);

    });
```

but it didn't work..I still get `403 error`

So,I tried to modify the data in `ajax` call

```
var create_note = function() {
    var data = { title:title, slug:slug ,csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'};
    ...
    var args = { type:"POST", url:"/create/", data:data, complete:done };
    $.ajax(args);

};
```

Still it causes 403 error..

Please tell me what should be done to correct this..I saw the 
[django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) about this,but I am confused how to make use of that.Should I copy the entire `jQuery(document).ajaxSend(...` code in to my javascript file..I am really confused here..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ([as the document you linked to suggests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax)) copy that entire `ajaxSend` method ...

You dont need to modify it in any way - it is a complete solution - the `ajaxSend` method is actually an event handler for the `ajaxSend` event. Its triggered when you use the `.ajax` method in jQuery. [See the ajaxSend docs here](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/)

The method linked in the above document appends the correct `X-CSRFToken` header to your AJAX request. You can then use your first method for sending the AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks @ManseUK, I came across this suggestion too..http://stackoverflow.com/a/5107878/1291096

Comment: ? this doesn't really answer the question of *where* one is meant to put the ajaxSend code. Just in the html file? On a notepad?

Comment: @bharal its a JavaScript method - so either in a library you link to or on a page that requires it - the question wasnt where to put it - it was how to fix the problem ....