# CSRF protection always failing when trying to upload file with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-csrf, jqxhr

Few days before i learned that [we can make file uploads with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2320097/842622). So i tried to build an app that uploads selected file when other parts of form being filled by user.

my app has two models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(...)
    title = ...
    desc = ...

class TempImg(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(...)
    posted_by = ...
    posted_at = ...
```

That form used to make a post, here you can see temp_image as hidden input:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    temp_image = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

When user selects image, this javascript code uploads it and puts returning id value to temp_image field of form:

```
// here is a function that gets csrftoken, [which is taken from docs
// https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

csrftoken = ...

form = new FormData();
form.append("image", dataURLToBlob(resizedImgData));
form.append("csrftoken", csrftoken)

$.ajax({
    url: '/upload/',
    data: form,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#uploadingIndicator").show()
    },
    success: function(data){
        $("#id_temp_image").val(data['id'])
        $("#uploadingIndicator").hide();
    }
});
```

Everything seems OK to me but, there is a problem that my view always return 403. CSRF verification error.

Can anybody have an idea where should i look at? I am going to use csrf_exemt if i can not find solution...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562494/csrf-with-ajax-and-django-post?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
form.append("csrfmiddlewaretoken", csrftoken)
```

While you were trying to do `form.append("csrftoken", csrftoken)`