# what's wrong with this method for csrf token with ajax form post in django?

Tags: ajax, django, csrf

I've been looking for few days now how to convert form submissions to ajax with jquery, and the csrf token issue is puzzling me.

I solved the problem by adding the javascript snippet found here :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

But when stumbling on stackoverflow, I found simpler answers (not the first one):
[Django CSRF check failing with an Ajax POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request)

Some answers suggest to simply add the following to the post data: 
csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'

But this seems too good to be true, if that was that easy, why would we need to copy the long snippet from the django website ? Also there's a quick comment to one of the replies about static JS. I don't really get it.

Could anyone please explain why the simplest solution isn't the best, and give some practical examples ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two solutions are effectively doing exactly the same thing. Supplying the `csrftoken` to Django in the request. They're just doing it in different ways.

**'Simpler' option**

For a single jQuery call in a Django template, it may be simpler to use the `{{ csrf_token }}` tag to add to the post data. However as soon as there are multiple calls in multiple places, it becomes harder to maintain.

**jQuery Code**

On the other hand, the jQuery code:

- Can be included in one place, in a static .js file
- Doesn't need to be in a django template
- Can be included in multiple pages
- Works for all jQuery Ajax calls without modifying the individual calls
- Includes working with any third party jQuery libraries
- Is the same everywhere, so easy to share in the Django documentation

**How it works**

The extra complexity of the jQuery code is due to it running in the browser, without access to any Django variables.

The code works by attaching to a jQuery event used for every Ajax call. It looks up `csrftoken` from a cookie stored in the browser, determines whether to send the token, based on the request type and host, and sends the token as a `HTTP header`, instead of including it in the `POST` data.