# how to send url parameter in POST request without form

Tags: django, url, httpwebrequest, url-parameters

I have to pass a parameter in url. I can't send it in as usual GET request the variable and value is shown in the address bar with the request. So, the end user can change the value for this variable value and send request which will be processed.

```
href="url=/admin/usermanagement/?flag=2
```

I want to send this hiding `flag=2`

now this goes as a GET request and it is seen in the address bar. Please give your suggestion if you have any idea on changing this to POST to hide and send the value.

Comment: moving to POST requests will only add some obscurity, it won't stop users from changing the value and making requests.

Comment: hmm yes I know they can still view it using firebug. But, that security level is enough in my case. Anyways, I welcome if you have any good suggestion for this case. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 11):

You can still use a html form but "hide" it from the user:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="myform" method="post" action="/">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="flag" value="2" />
            <a href="#" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();return false;">Let's go!</a>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the view:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            flag = request.POST['flag']
            # TODO use flag
        except KeyError:
            print 'Where is my flag?'

    return render_to_response('index.html', {},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: This worked brilliantly for me, exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Maximas If it answered your question, you should accept the answer by clicking the check mark on the left side of the answer.

Comment: @sort-of-a-beginner This isn't my post?

Comment: @Maximas Sorry, I thought you were answering Borges question, thus causing me to assume it was your question. I'll have to look closer next time.

Comment: Why the `a` tag with `onclick` attribute? why not just a submit button?

Answer (score 3):

You can use AJAX to get rid of forms entirely.

Just add this to your JavaScript:

```
function postTo(url, query) {
    var request = (XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject());
    request.open('POST', url, true);
    request.send(query);
}
```

Then call with something like this:

```
postTo('/admin/usermanagement/','flag=2');
```

Note that this will **NOT** reload the page. If you want to reload the page, use Borges' answer.

Comment: What about CSRF verification? I get a verification error.

Comment: @GobSmack There's an answer to that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request) using JQuery.