# Django form not getting submitted facing attribute error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to store a field value from a webform to django database, my `models.py` and `views.py` are given below. I am facing **AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'
*** error I am new to django and python, please let me know my mistake here.

[VIEWS.PY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3NKn.png)

[MODEL.PY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6rRt.png)

Comment: Put the `action=''`, empty, since you are submitting to the same view/endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your view,

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        #No need to call index view again,
        #it's already been called.
            return redirect('home') #redirection.
    else:
        form = PageForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form':form})
```

**urls.py**

```
from . import views

url(r'^index/$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^home/$', views.home, name='home')
```

You could use render() shortcut function,

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

```
render(request, template[, dictionary][, context_instance][, content_type][, status][, current_app])
```

render() is a brand spanking new shortcut for render_to_response in 1.3 that will automatically useRequestContext that I will most definitely be using from now on.

The `action` part in your html form, is where you define the endpoint or url to where the form is submitting. Since, your view accepts the post data, then your `action=''` needs to be kept empty, which means you are posting to the same view itself.

Comment: In my index.html what should i use for the action part? I am getting a404 error after clicking submit. Where should i redirect the page?

Comment: You may need to write another view and redirect to that view, I could show you an example, in my answer

Comment: Please show. And how is the feild value savde to db if i am redirecting it to a new view. I dont find the value in db afvter submission.

Comment: For that you need to show your forms.py, but please copy paste the code into the question, don't add link to an image. I have updated my answer

Comment: You just need to put the `action=''` in the template.

Comment: I have added my forms.py to questions comment and I am able to store the value to db now, but getting namerror once submitting form

Comment: Couple things to remember next time, if you are adding additional information about the question, then edit the question and add it. Don't post it in the comments. Comments are there for their purpose. Your code need to be in the question itself.

Comment: Yeah sure, I am new here and didn't find the edit button. Now this makes some sense to me. The error is rectified. Thanks for the help. How can I use ajax here without redirection. Just tell me a proper way to achieve it, no need to code for me. Is the ajax need to be written on front end here or does django have anything for this?

Comment: You could write an ajax function in the front end and write a corresponding view in the django, like the above mentioned view.

Comment: I have one more question for you. I have a HTML file basically a web form  with me which is developed using bootstrap, jQuery(without using django) and I need to connect this to django. Can I do this? If yes any hints please

Comment: Yes, you can... You could grab the data posted from `request.POST` in the view.

Comment: Refer the documentation for more, actually everything is clearly documented in django documentation

Comment: Don't I need to use forms.py then? Can you elaborate

Comment: Forms are just tools for handling multiple datas. By reading more about django forms, I think you would understand. Forms are not mandatory, but they could become useful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773144/how-to-send-url-parameter-in-post-request-without-form refer this question

Comment: Yes I am on the way reading the documentation, but its taking time and this is an immediate requirement for me. So posted it here without  wasting time. I am yet to connect all the dots, may be I can once I complete the documentation atleast

Comment: how can i use templating in already developed html page, I mean the example we discussed here uses some templating in index.html, but in my html file created using bootstrap and jq, how can i use this templating?? simply how should i connect it ? Should i include this templating in my html file? if so how? consider an input field in html, how can i send its value entered by user to backend]

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py there is an error in the context part, {'form':form} itself is the context there is no need to include 'context' again and also include the request
`render(request,'index.html',{'form':form})`

Comment: In my index.html what should i use for the action part? I am getting a404 error after clicking submit. Where should i redirect the page? – krish 1 min ago   edit