# jQuery: setting up CSRF token for Django not working

Tags: jquery, django, csrf

my `jQuery` function looks like

```
$(function() {
    // activate "New" buttons if input is not empty
    $('form input[type="text"]').live('keyup', function() {
        var val = $.trim(this.value);
        $(this).next("button").prop('disabled', val.length === 0);
    });

    $("body").on("submit","form",function(e){
        // do not submit the form
        e.preventDefault();

        // handle everything yourself
        var $form = $(this);
        var title = $form.closest('.video-detail').find('.title').text();
        var entryTitle = $form.find('.input-small').val();
        console.debug(title);
        console.debug(entryTitle);  

        $.ajaxSetup({ 
             beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                 function getCookie(name) {
                     var cookieValue = null;
                     if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                         var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                         for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                             var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                             // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                         if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                             cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                             break;
                         }
                     }
                 }
                 return cookieValue;
                 }
                 if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
                     // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
                     xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
                 }
             } 
        }); 

        // send the data to the server using .ajax() or .post()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'addVideo',
            data: {
                video_title: title,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
        }).done(function(){
            alert('done');
        });
    });
});
```

This is based on answer [Django CSRF check failing with an Ajax POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request)

My `html` looks like

```
<form class="new-playlist form-inline" onclick="event.stopPropagation()">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" class="input-small">
    <button class="btn btn-danger create-playlist-button" type="submit" disabled="disabled">New</button>
</form>
```

When I debug the code in Firefox, I see post values as

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken {{ csrf_token }}
video_title The Who - Who Are You?
```

How can I populate the `{{ csrf_token }}` value?

Thank you

Comment: what does `getCookie('csrftoken')` return?

Answer (score 9):

In my case I have a template in which I don't want to have a `<form></form>` element. But I still want to make AJAX POST requests using jQuery.

I got 403 errors, due to CSRF cookie being null, even if I followed the django docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/csrf/). The solution is in the same page, mentioning the `ensure_csrf_cookie` decorator.

My CSRF cookie did get set when I added this at the top of my `views.py`:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie
@ensure_csrf_cookie
```

Also, please note that in this case you *do not need* the DOM element in your markup / template: `{% csrf_token %}`

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="SOME_TOKEN">`

Above is the markup outputted by django. You want to grab the value of SOME_TOKEN. You will not be able to get it using the django template engine mixed with javascript since it will already be rendered into the input hidden.

I would wrap my `{{ csrf_token }}` in a span/div and then use jquery to locate that span/div and grab the [value](http://api.jquery.com/val/) of the input inside the span/div.