# Jquery cross site login with GET + POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, csrf

I am attempting to script a login to a django site. I have used Chrome's Advanced REST Client to post credentials and successfully login. In theory I should be able to use jQuery to script login.

In the REST client I issued two requests:

1) GET request to retrieve a csrftoken

2) POST request with the 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' = (csrftoken from first GET)

This succeeds.

I have tried to emulate similar functionality using jQuery, however when I issue a GET via

```
response = $.get( 'http://site.com' )
//response.getAllResponseHeaders() does not yield a csrftoken ?
```

Without the csrftoken, the subsequent POST will yield a 403.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203304/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-rails

Comment: Don't I need to first retrieve a csrf token from the server? How is the token retrieved in the REST client?

Comment: You could set an endpoint returning token, but seems there is not helper to return just token.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: setting up CSRF token for Django not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812694/jquery-setting-up-csrf-token-for-django-not-working)