# Nginx Webhook Allow IP Django

Tags: django, configuration, nginx, ip, webhooks

I'm new to Nginx, and I am having some problems allowing a webhook access to the server. Whenever the webhook tries to send a POST to my Django server, I get this in my access log:

54.234.20.81 - - [02/Jan/2013:18:11:57 +0000] "POST /contracts/events HTTP/1.1" 403 2319 "-" "-"
54.234.20.81 - - [02/Jan/2013:18:11:58 +0000] "POST /contracts/events HTTP/1.1" 403 2319 "-" "-"
54.234.20.81 - - [02/Jan/2013:18:11:58 +0000] "POST /contracts/events HTTP/1.1" 403 2319 "-" "-"

I'm not sure how to grant access to this IP such that it is not forbidden. I'm hosting on Ramhost, and the Nginx directory appears to be /etc/nginx/. This directory has a nginx.conf, and also a sites-available folder and a sites-enabled folder.

Here is the configuration file in sites-available (there is a symlink in sites-enabled to this file):

```
upstream djangoserv {
server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name nameblr.com www.nameblr.com;
    access_log /home/yorango/yorangosite/logs/yorangosite-access.log;
    error_log /home/yorango/yorangosite/logs/yorangosite-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/yorango/yorangosite/static/;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/yorango/yorangosite/static/;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
        # host and port to fastcgi server
        allow 54.242.81.184;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
        fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^()(.*)$;
    }
}
```

And here is the nginx.conf file, which is in the /etc/nginx/ folder.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

I'm not sure if the "allow 54.242.81.184;" is in the correct place, or how the file in sites-available works together with the nginx.conf, but any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the problem is Nginx? Do you have CSRF protection enabled for your Django project? I'm pretty sure Django will emit a 403 when the CSRF-check fails.

Check out this question for more info: [Django CSRF check failing with an Ajax POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request)

Comment: That is a good point. However, I seem to be having the same problem even after I added a @csrf_exempt decorator the the view that is being blocked.

Comment: Needed to kill the server and restart it. The csrf was the issue!