# posting formdata with ajax has csrf error in django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, form-data

I'm new to ajax and django and I'm trying to send a file in a form using formdata and ajax but I'm getting csrf token missing error and I've searched alot but can't solve this problem.Should I use cookies?if so,how?.I really need help.My codes are here:

**urls.py**

...

```
url(r'^administration/library/add_ebook/ajax/$',upload_ebook_ajax, name='upload_ebook_ajax'),
```

...

**forms.py**

```
class EbookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ebook
        fields = ('ebook_title', 'ebook_publisher','ebook_publication_date','ebook_Type','ebook_keywords','ebook_preview','ebook_url','ebook_categories', )
```

**views.py**

```
@transaction.atomic()
def upload_ebook_ajax(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EbookForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():

        form.save()
        data['form_is_valid'] = True

    else:
        data['form_is_valid'] = False
else:
    form = EbookForm()

context = {'form': form}
data['html_form'] = render_to_string('upldebook.html',context,request=request)
return JsonResponse(data)
```

**upldebook.html**

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% crispy form %}
```

**add_ebook.html**

```
<div class="c">
                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-file-upload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js' %}"></script>
                    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-file-upload/jquery.iframe-transport.js' %}"></script>
                    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-file-upload/jquery.fileupload.js' %}"></script>
                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'upload_ebook_ajax' %}" class="js-upload-ebook-form">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    <div class="frmclass"></div>



                <script src="{% static 'uploadebook.js' %}"></script>


                    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

**uploadebook.js**

```
//for showing form
 $.ajax({
      url: '/administration/library/add_ebook/ajax',
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        $(".frmclass").html(data.html_form);
      }
    });
//for form submit
    $(".js-upload-ebook-form").submit( function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var frmdt = new FormData($('form').get(0)); //I don't know what is 'form' :|
    frmdt.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{ csrf_token }}');
    $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    data: frmdt,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert("SUCCESS1");
        window.location = "/"
    }

    });
    return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed this:

```
data:  new FormData(this)
```

and now it works.

Thanks to this link:
http://phppot.com/php/php-ajax-image-upload/

Answer (score 2):

One solution I use is to add `@csrf_exempt` to your ajax methods (it might decrease security):

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def upload_ebook_ajax(request):
    # your code
```

Comment: thanks @igo but when I use this, eveything sounds good but nothing is saved into my database :(
even alerts SUCCESS1 but nothing is saved

Comment: well that's completely different problem... maybe you made a GET request or form is invalid...

Comment: no it's POST and my form is valid too because I'm validating in my view

Answer (score 2):

`{% csrf_token %}` puts a hidden html input inside your form, so if you just the form with original inputs, it should work.

```
data: $(this).serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the data field, the token will be posted along with it

```
data: frmdt.serialize(),
```

Read this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request?rq=1) page for more, your answer could be there

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: frmdt.serialize is not a function