# React Error : __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_jquery___default(...)(...).modal is not a function

Tags: jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a react project with Bootstrap 4. Bootstrap has been imported through CDN.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

what I wanted is to show/hide a modal if a condition is satisfied. I have already imported jquery also using

```
npm install jquery --save
```

in component

```
import $ from 'jquery'; <-to import jquery

$('#addSupModal').modal('show'); <- to show modal
```

but during the execution time when the above line gets executed, it shows an error like

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_jquery___default(...)(...).modal is not a function
```

I read about this error and it says maybe because jquery is imported twice with CDN and npm. I don't know for sure what the reason. But I also tried importing jquery from only one method but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your import `import $ from 'jquery'` creates a *local* variable named `$` inside your module, which then gets used by `$('#addSupModal').modal('show')` (instead of the global `$` you wanted).

The quickest fix would be to explicitly use the jQuery `$` from the global context (which has been extended with your `$.modal()` because you referenced that in your script tag when you did `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`):

```
window.$('#addSupModal').modal('show')
```

It would be better though to not include the jQuery and plugins with script tags at all, because that way you are creating *implicit* dependencies (which is, your module cannot run without those `script` tags). Instead, import Bootstrap as well:

```
import $ from 'jquery'; // <-to import jquery
import 'bootstrap';

$('#addSupModal').modal('show'); // <- to show modal
```

Comment: saved me...after half an hour of reading bullshit on stackoverflow. Importing bootstrap is missing from all other answers.

Comment: You are a saviour. I have been struggling with this error for days. Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: I got this **Uncaught TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.cookie is not a function**.  I followed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43567052/csrf-token-of-django-into-vuejs-when-seperate-them