# Getting 'type error.... $(...).modal is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, bootstrap-5, bootstrap5-modal

I am trying to create and edit function to update notes by user (in a REACT project), using bootstrap modals, but here is the error I get

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default()(...).modal is not a function
updateNote Notes.js:16
onClick NoteItem.js:15
React 23
js index.js:6
factory react refresh:6
Webpack 3
    __webpack_require__
    <anonymous>
    <anonymous>
```

I tried going through some posts on the forum like including jquery library before bootstrap, but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
    import React,{ useContext,useEffect,useRef } from "react";
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'bootstrap';
import noteContext from "../context/notes/NoteContext"
import AddNote from "./AddNote";
import NoteItem from "./NoteItem";

export const Notes=() => {
    const context=useContext(noteContext)
    const { notes,getNotes }=context
    useEffect(() => {
        getNotes()
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    },[])
    const ref=useRef(null)
    const updateNote=async (note) => {
        console.log("working")
        $(ref).modal('toggle')
    }
    return (
        <>
            <AddNote />
            <button ref={ref} type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                Launch demo modal
            </button>

            <div className="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Note</h5>
                            <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-body">
                            ...
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row my-3">
                <h1>Your Notes</h1>
                {notes.map((note) => {
                    return <NoteItem key={note._id} updateNote={updateNote} note={note} />
                })}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Also here is my index.html (I removed the jquery link as it wasn't working):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  <title>iNotebook - Your notes on the cloud</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ae578fcfec.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What am I missing?

I found another post which had a similar issue ([React Error : __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_jquery___default(...)(...).modal is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464915/react-error-webpack-imported-module-4-jquery-default-modal-is-no)) importing bootstrap didn't work either because It had dependency issue with @popperjs/core which i installed but then got more errors:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './modifiers/index.js' in '/home/alien/codes/webDev/react/inotebook/node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib'
[0] ERROR in ./node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/index.js 2:0-37
[0] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './modifiers/index.js' in '/home/alien/codes/webDev/react/inotebook/node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib'
[0] 
[0] ERROR in ./node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js 20:0-37
[0] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './modifiers/index.js' in '/home/alien/codes/webDev/react/inotebook/node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib'
[0] 
[0] webpack compiled with 2 errors
```

then I didn't find anything to solve it, let me know if this method was relevant or not or if there is anything else i need to add to this

Just to give a better idea here is the tutorial i am following: https://youtu.be/J5hGX5_XZDk . it is quite old so there must be an update in syntax in newer versions, which i am not sure of, so let me know if there is something that needs to change. And before you ask, initially i followed this tutorial by every word, but then i had to go through official bootstrap documentation to remove some errors which made the app crash, so is there something else that i need to change too?

updated code:

```
import React,{ useContext,useEffect,useRef } from "react";
import noteContext from "../context/notes/NoteContext"
import AddNote from "./AddNote";
import NoteItem from "./NoteItem";

export const Notes=() => {
    const context=useContext(noteContext)
    const { notes,getNotes }=context
    useEffect(() => {
        getNotes()
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    },[])
    const ref=useRef(null)
    const updateNote=async (note) => {
        console.log("working")
        ref.current.click()
    }
    return (
        <>
            <AddNote />
            <button ref={ref} type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                Launch demo modal
            </button>

            <div className="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Note</h5>
                            <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-body">
                            ...
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row my-3">
                <h1>Your Notes</h1>
                {notes.map((note) => {
                    return <NoteItem key={note._id} updateNote={updateNote} note={note} />
                })}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function with bootstrap Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064176/typeerror-modal-is-not-a-function-with-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: no it doesn't, the solutions in there don't make a difference in the error

Answer (score 2):

[Bootstrap V5 has many breaking changes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/). One of them is the removal of jquery.

This is how bootstrap 5 would [toggle a modal using javascript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#toggle).

```
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'), {
  keyboard: false
});

myModal.toggle();
```

---

You can also show/hide modal with the data attributes. But its different from whats done in Bootsrap 4. [They have namespaced the attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69546376/17447) to `data-bs-*` (from `data-*`)

Look at the documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#live-demo

You code uses <s>data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"</s> but the example shows `data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"`.

Also <s>`data-dismiss`</s> became `data-bs-dismiss`

Comment: Isn't using React with jQuery alongside considered a bad idea generally?

Comment: of course yes. jQuery mainly helped us with the IE era. Many major libraries had that as a dependency. If you were using BootStrap v4.0 you had no choice. It was a dependency

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out (i was reading the old documentation then i think lol), i made the appropriate changes and updated the new code in the post, but when it just shows that `ref.toggle` is not a function, i also tried `ref.current.toggle` and it shows the same thing, so i followed the tutorial again, but when i did, nothing really happens (i have updated it in the post) what is going wrong here? because the console.log shows that the function is running.