# How to pass value to the url in Django while event occurs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to send a value to the URL, whenever event occurs it shows:

> error that the Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /mapreq
>   [03/Nov/2017 11:08:27] "POST /mapreq HTTP/1.1" 403 2502

This is the script:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('path').mouseup(function () {
                document.getElementById('state').innerHTML = $(this).attr('aria-label');
                var state_lbl = document.getElementById('state').innerHTML = $(this).attr('aria-label');
                loadstate(state_lbl);

            })
        });

        function loadstate(state_lal) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "mapreq",
                data: {'state': state_lal}
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django CSRF check failing with an Ajax POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to pass the csrf token.** It is important to protect your users data.

With a [JavaScriptCookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/) you can get it like that:

```
var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
var data = new FormData();

data.append('state',state_lal);
data.append('csrftoken', csrftoken);


 function loadstate(state_lal) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mapreq",
            data: data,
        });
```

If you do not want to use a third-party just have a look at this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/). Here is also the third-party mentioned but also the way without it.

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py file comment or remove  the 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' line from middelware classes.

```
`MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
#     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
)`
```

Then you will not get the error message related to CSRF token.

Otherwise Add CSRF key in parameter list like:

```
'data: { CSRF: getCSRFTokenValue()}'
```

Comment: Really ? You should not do that ! csrf-token are very important to protect your users data.

Comment: The above thing is for simple use case .
But yes it is important to keep csrf token for safety .

For that you need to include csrf key in the parameter 

data: { CSRF: getCSRFTokenValue()}