# Imagefield not saving in django cms plugin form working with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-cms

Hi I am new on django i was creating custom plugin in django cms it is the form other fields get saved easily, but the image field is not getting saved.

Here is my code let me know if I am missing something I am really stuck over here your help will be really appreciated.

## models.py

```
    class Blogs(models.Model):


        name = models.CharField(u'Name',
            blank=True,
            default='',
            help_text=u'Your name',
            max_length=64,
        )

        description = models.TextField(u'Description',
             blank=True,
             default='',
             help_text=u'Enter your Blog.',
        )


        comments = models.TextField(u'Short Description',
            blank=True,
            default='',
            help_text=u'Short title of the Blog.',
        )

        images = models.ImageField(
            upload_to='blog_image',
            default='blog_image/black.png',
            blank=True
        )

        # Meta, non-form data
        contact_date = models.DateTimeField(
            u'contact date',
            blank=True,
            default=timezone.now,
            help_text=u'When this person completed the contact form.',
        )

        was_contacted = models.BooleanField(u'has been contacted?',
                                            default=False,
                                            help_text=u'Check this if someone has already reached out to this person.',
                                            )

        notes = models.TextField(u'contact notes',
                                 blank=True,
                                 default='',
                                 help_text=u'Internal notes relating to contacting this person.',
                                 )

        referer = models.CharField(u'referring page',
                                   blank=True,
                                   default='',
                                   help_text=u'This is the page the visitor was on before coming to the contact page.',
                                   max_length=2048,
                                   )

        def send_notification_email(self):

            subject.txt', {
                'contact': self,
            })

            email_body = render_to_string('contacts/notification-body.txt', {
                'contact': self,
            })

            try:
                send_mail(
                    email_subject,
                    email_body,
                    settings.SERVER_EMAIL,
                    settings.MANAGERS,
                    fail_silently=(not settings.DEBUG)
                )

            except Exception:

                if (settings.DEBUG):
                    raise

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

            if not self.pk:

                try:
                    self.send_notification_email()
                except:

                    pass

            super(Blogs, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return '%s (%s)' % (self.name, str(self.contact_date),) 



    class BlogPluginModel(CMSPlugin):

        title = models.CharField(u'title',
            blank=True,
            help_text=u'Optional. Title of the widget.',
            max_length=64,
        )

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title
```

## cms_plugins.py

```
    class BlogPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
        model = BlogPluginModel
        name = _("Blog Form")
        render_template = "blogs/_blogs_widget.html"


        def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):

            try:
                path = context['request'].path
            except:
                path = ''

            form = BlogAjaxForm(initial={'referer': path})

            context.update({
                "title": instance.title,
                "form": form,
                "form_action": reverse("blogging_form"),
            })
            return context

    plugin_pool.register_plugin(BlogPlugin)
```

## forms.py

```
    class BlogBaseForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            abstract = True

        required_css_class = 'required'

        verify_email = forms.EmailField(
            label=u'Verify email',
            help_text=u'Please retype your email address here.',
            max_length=255,
            required=True,
        )

        required_fields = []



    class blogForm(BlogBaseForm):

        images=forms.ImageField(help_text="Upload image: ", required=False)

        class Meta:
            model = Blogs
            fields = [
                'name','images', 'description', 'comments', 'referer',
            ]
            widgets = {
                'referer': forms.HiddenInput(),

            }


        required_fields = ['name', 'email', 'verify_email', ]



    class BlogAjaxForm(BlogBaseForm):
        images=forms.ImageField(help_text="Upload image: ", required=False)
        class Meta:
            model = Blogs
            fields = ['name','images', 'description','comments','referer', ]
            widgets = { 'referer': forms.HiddenInput(),}
```

## view.py

```
    class BlogFormView(FormView):
        form_class = BlogBaseForm
        template_name = 'contacts/contact_form.html'

        def get_initial(self):
            """
            still preserve this original HTTP_REFERER.
            """
            initial = super(BlogFormView, self).get_initial()
            initial['referer'] = self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', ''),
            return initial

        def get_success_url(self):
            page = get_object_or_404(
                Page,
                reverse_id='blog_form_submission',
                publisher_is_draft=False
            )
            return page.get_absolute_url()

        def form_valid(self, form):
            self.object = form.save()
            return super(BlogFormView, self).form_valid(form)


    class AjaxableResponseMixin(object):


        def __init__(self):
            self.request = None
            self.object = Blogs

        def render_to_json_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
            data = json.dumps(context)
            response_kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
            return HttpResponse(data, **response_kwargs)

        def form_invalid(self, form):
            response = super(AjaxableResponseMixin, self).form_invalid(form)
            if self.request.is_ajax():
                return self.render_to_json_response(form.errors)  # , status=400)
            else:
                return response

        def form_valid(self, form):


            response = super(AjaxableResponseMixin, self).form_valid(form)
            if self.request.is_ajax():
                data = {
                    'pk': self.object.pk,
                }
                return self.render_to_json_response(data)
            else:
                return response



    class BlogFormAjaxView(AjaxableResponseMixin, FormView):
        form_class = BlogAjaxForm
        http_method_names = [u'post'] 
        template_name = 'contacts/_contact_widget.html'
        form = BlogAjaxForm(http_method_names)

        def get_success_url(self):
            page = get_object_or_404(
                Page,
                reverse_id='blog_form_submission',
                publisher_is_draft=False
            )
            return page.get_absolute_url()

        def form_valid(self, form):

            self.object = form.save(commit=True)
            return super(BlogFormAjaxView, self).form_valid(form)
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [      
    url(
        r'^blogging_form/$',
        BlogFormAjaxView.as_view(),
        name='blogging_form'
    ),
    url(r'^$', BlogFormView.as_view(), name='Blog_Form'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

## _blog_widget.html

```
{% load i18n static sekizai_tags %}
{% addtoblock "js" %}<script src="{% static 'blogs/scripts/Blogs.js' %}"></script>
{% endaddtoblock %}
{% addtoblock "css" %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'contacts/css/styles.css' %}">
{% endaddtoblock %}
{% addtoblock "js" %}
<script src="{% static 'http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js' %}"></script>
{% endaddtoblock %}
<div class="Blogs-plugin plugin">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="Blog-form">
      {% if title %}<h3>{{ title }}</h3>{% endif %}
      <form method="post" action="{{ form_action  }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
        {% if hidden.name == 'referer' %}
        <input type="hidden" name="{{ hidden.name }}" value="{{ hidden.value }}">
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        {% for visible in form.visible_fields %}
        <div class="field-wrapper field-row half {{ visible.css_classes }}">
          {{ visible.label_tag }}
          <div class="help-text">{{ visible.help_text }}</div>
          <div class="error empty"></div>

          {{ visible }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>


      <div class="legend"><span class="required">*</span> Required field
      </div>
      <div class="success" style="display:none">Thank you, a member of our 
             team will contact you shortly, if appropriate.
      </div>
      <div class="errors" style="display:none"><span class="form-errors"> 
      </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Blogs.js

```
(function($){
          "use strict";

          $(function(){

            $('.Blogs-plugin input[type=submit]').on('click', 
  function(evt){
              var $form = $(this).parents('form').eq(0);

              function handleResponse(data){
                if (data.pk) { // Success!
                  $form.siblings('.success').html(data.success).show(100);



                  $form.add('.legend').hide(100);
                }

                else { // Validation Issues...
                  //
                  // data will a dictionary like so:
                  // { 'field_name': ['error1', 'error2'], ... }
                  //
                  $form.find('.error').empty();
                  $.each(data, function(key, value){
                    var $field = $form.find('input[name='+key+']').first();
                    $field.parents('.fieldwrapper').find('.error').html(value.join(' '));
                  });


                  if (data.__all__) {
                    $form.siblings('.errors').find('.form- 
     errors').html(data.__all__.join(' '));
                  }
                  else {
                    $form.siblings('.errors').find('.form-errors').empty();
                  }
                  $form.siblings('.errors').show(100);
                }
              }

              evt.preventDefault();
              $form.siblings('.errors, .success').hide(100);


              $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                data: $form.serialize(),
              }).always(handleResponse);
            });
          });
        }(window.jQuery));
```

Comment: You're not passing the CSRF value in your ajax call. If you `POST` (with the CSRF middleware enabled) then you need to include the CSRF value in that ajax call. There's a good answer here; https://stackoverflow.com/a/5107878/1199464