# Handling Ajax request in Django without form

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, backend

I have a list of things in my html with an ajax request to pass the data-measure value to views.py :

```
<ul>
   <li><a class="measure" href="#" data-measure="m_0001">Measure_0001</a></li>
   <li><a class="measure" href="#" data-measure="m_0002">Measure_0002</a></li>
   <li><a class="measure" href="#" data-measure="m_0003">Measure_0003</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".measure").click(function(){
var measure = {'measure': this.getAttribute("data-measure")};
$.ajax({
    url : "prueba/", // the endpoint
    type : "POST", // http method
    data : measure,

    success : function (data) {
         //Success 
    }
});
```

In this file 
**views.py** I want to get the value to make a query to my database.

```
def prueba(request):
  response_data =  '{}'
  if request.user.is_authenticated:
    if request.method == 'POST':
      measure = request.POST.get('measure', None)
      //request to database

      return JsonResponse(response_data, safe=False)
    else:
      response_data =  '{"nothing to see": "this is not happening"}'
      return JsonResponse(response_data, safe=False)
```

When I click the item of the list, I have this error:

"*Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.*)"

I do not understand where I have to put the csrf_token in order for it to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at this part of [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#ajax)?

Comment: This answer covers the topic quite well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5107878/2174832

Comment: Yes, there says that you have to put it inside the form tags but I'm not using a form in this case, just a list of elements

Comment: Thank you matyas! I think this worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden input element inside of your `ul` tag with value as `{{ csrf_token }}` like this:

```
<ul>
  <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='{{ csrf_token }}' />        
  <!-- your list elements -->
</ul>
```

and then in your jQuery do this:

```
$("ul .measure").on('click',function(){        
    var measure = {
        'measure': this.getAttribute("data-measure"),
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
       };
    // your ajax call
 });
```