# django error ajax CSRF token missing or incorrect without jquery

Tags: javascript, python, django

django csrf_token error 403 with js

```
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var links = document.querySelectorAll('form')

    for (var i = 0; i <  links.length; i++) {
        var link = links[i]
        link.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()

            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText
                }
            }

            httpRequest.open('POST', this.getAttribute('action'), true)
            httpRequest.send()

        })
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django CSRF check failing with an Ajax POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request)

Comment: @dan-klasson Op is not using jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set headers on `XMLHttpRequest` by doing:

```
var token = '{{csrf_token}}';

var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", token);
```