# Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.) Django

Tags: html, jquery, django, ajax, forms

I have included `{% csrf_token %}` in my HTML form(which includes textboxes and some checkboxes) in Django still I get `Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)` error because of `processData:false` in AJAX.
If I try removing `processData:false` from AJAX the form only keeps loading without any result. In browser console I get the following error:`Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` .

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django CSRF check failing with an Ajax POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request)

Comment: can you send the code of your HTML form

Comment: @samir https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UFw49J3nUfOQtXyAvce6gYjFvOFon8v1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @LemanKirme please read the question and answer I linked in the comment above. CSRF token isnt send with ajax automatically, you have to add it manually. As explained in the question linked above. Read it.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I didn't understand that answer fully as I am a beginner in JavaScript n all...may you please tell me how exactly should I add automatically...for reference you can check my html code for which I gave the link above

Answer (score -2):

Place the decorator `@csrf_exempt` in the view you are calling.

Comment: Noo that doesn't work buddy...it give multivaluedict error...

Comment: I don't think that decorator causes that error, it just show the real one.