# What i'm missing for use Django with Ajax

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

i want to automatic update a string/field of a simple webpage. The field is the latest date, which i get from this function:

```
def get_latest_date2():
    now = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc) - datetime.timedelta(seconds=20)
    now_string = now.isoformat()
    return str(now_string[:-14]) + '0Z'
```

So, when i run my django project the time appears on the webpage, but it does not update itself (which is totally normal). So i tried to use ajax to automatic refresh the time, but i'm not getting it from myself. I still don't understand how to make the js script update the time field automatically without a manual update (F5).

Here my codes, and something things that i tried.

**forms.py**

```
from .models import Book

class TimeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ExactTime
        fields = ('time')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class ExactTime(models.Model):
    time = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . import API_LOL_txt

def updatetime(request):
    response_dic={}
    form_template='dashboard/dashboard-home.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        time = TimeForm(request.POST)
        response_dic['time'] = time
        return render(request,'dashboard/dashboard-home.html', response_dic)

    response_dic['time'] = API_LOL_txt.get_latest_date2()
    return render(request,'dashboard/dashboard-home.html', response_dic)
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

   <title>API LOL</title>
</head>
<body>

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static '/js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static '/js/update.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**dashboard-home.html**

```
{% extends 'dashboard/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h3>Dashboard home</h3>
    <div id=update-time>
        <p>Time: {{ time }} </p>
    </div>        
{% endblock content %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.updatetime, name='dashboard-home'),
]
```

**update.js**

```
var refreshStream = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {},
        success: function(data){
            $('#update-time').replaceWith($('#update-time',data));
        },
    });
}

var total_seconds = 1;
setInterval(function(){
    refreshStream();
},total_second * 1000);
```

I'm trying to learn how to use django and ajax, so sorry if there is something very wrong in my code.

Comment: Please don't make regular Ajax requests just to update a timer - it's dead easy to handle this in just client-side Javascript, so you don't have to have all your users hitting your server every second!

Comment: i know, but i wanna learn how to use, because i'll make a a webpage which needs update  a lot of values in real time. Ty for your answer

Comment: @gabrielfigueiredo it looks good to me, cant really tell where it could be going wrong. I suggest adding some 'console.log()' cmds in the javascript function to check whether it is running periodically or not. you will then be able to tell the source of the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django CSRF check failing with an Ajax POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request)