# Why is the csfr exempt decorator not working?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to send a 'POST' request from AJAX with `fetch` to a Django view with a `@csfr_exempt`decorator and I still get a `403 Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /profile/follow` error. Can someone explain why? (Newbie here).

This is the `.js`:

```
function follow_user(user, follower, action) {

fetch(`follow`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            user: user,
            follower: follower,
            action: action
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        document.querySelector("#followers-count").innerHTML = `Followers: ${data.followers}`
    });
console.log(console.log(`Schiscia: ${follower} ${action} ${user} ${data.followers}`));
```

and the view is:

```
@csrf_exempt
def follow(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.POST.get('user')
        follower = request.POST.get('follow')
        action = request.POST.get('action')

        target = User.objects.get(username=user)
        sourceusr = User.objects.get(username=follower)
        if action == 'follow':
            target.followers.append(sourceusr)
            sourceusr.following.append(target)
            return JsonResponse({'Following': target.following}, safe=False,
                                status=201)
```

Comment: Which authentication class you use or seted in settings.py?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I didn't add or delete anything in settings.py as I have never needed to before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django CSRF check failing with an Ajax POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request)

Answer (score 0):

Try with class base view.

```
 from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

 @method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
 class Follow(View):

    def post(self, request):
        user = request.POST.get('user')
        follower = request.POST.get('follow')
        action = request.POST.get('action')

        target = User.objects.get(username=user)
        sourceusr = User.objects.get(username=follower)
        if action == 'follow':
            target.followers.append(sourceusr)
            sourceusr.following.append(target)
            return JsonResponse({'Following': target.following}, safe=False,
                                status=201)
```

**OR**

```
 class Follow(View):
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(Follow, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def post(self, request):
        user = request.POST.get('user')
        follower = request.POST.get('follow')
        action = request.POST.get('action')

        target = User.objects.get(username=user)
        sourceusr = User.objects.get(username=follower)
        if action == 'follow':
            target.followers.append(sourceusr)
            sourceusr.following.append(target)
            return JsonResponse({'Following': target.following}, safe=False,
                                status=201)
```

**urls.py:**

```
path('follow/', Follow.as_view(), name='follow'),
```

Comment: Actually no, it still gives me 403.

Comment: I updated my ans. see this.Use class base view instead of function base view.