# How to fetch data from DRF API using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-rest-framework

I have serialized my django model data, I now want to add the data to a variable in jquery , how can i do this ? the variable in jquery named 'trackUrl' needs to read a list of the audio source urls, if you see in my API tracks page I have the data for each user, but I'm not sure how to approach this, any ideas ?

serializers.py

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Music
        fields = ['track']
```

views.py

```
class TrackViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Music.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TrackSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        songs = Music.objects.all().filter(artist=user)
        return songs
```

Django Rest API: tracks

```
Track List
GET /music/tracks/
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "track": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/path/to/audio/1-05_Isnt_She_Lovely.mp3"
    },
    {
        "track": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/path/to/audio/01_-_We_Will_Rock_You_1.mp3"
    },
    {
        "track": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/path/to/audio/08_Dont_Give_Hate_A_Chance.MP3"
    },
    {
        "track": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/path/to/audio/01_Closer.mp3"
    },
    {
        "track": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/path/to/audio/01_Empty_Garden.mp3"
    }
]
```

jquery

```
<script>
$(function()
{
    var playerTrack = $("#player-track"), bgArtwork = $('#bg-artwork'), bgArtworkUrl,
     albumName = $('#album-name'), trackName = $('#track-name'), albumArt = $('#album-art'),
      sArea = $('#s-area'), seekBar = $('#seek-bar'), trackTime = $('#track-time'), insTime = $('#ins-time'),
       sHover = $('#s-hover'), playPauseButton = $("#play-pause-button"),  i = playPauseButton.find('i'), 
       tProgress = $('#current-time'), tTime = $('#track-length'), seekT, seekLoc, seekBarPos, cM, ctMinutes, 
       ctSeconds, curMinutes, curSeconds, durMinutes, durSeconds, playProgress, bTime, nTime = 0, buffInterval = null, 
       tFlag = false, albums = ['Dawn','Me & You','Electro Boy','Home','Proxy (Original Mix)'], 
       trackNames = ['Empty Garden','Closer','Dont Give Hate a Chance','We will rock you','Isnt she lovely'], 
       albumArtworks = ['_1','_2','_3','_4','_5']; 
       var trackUrl = [],
         playPreviousTrackButton = $('#play-previous'), playNextTrackButton = $('#play-next'), currIndex = -1;
```

Comment: Please remove all the unnecessary code and bring more focus to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you asking how to fetch from API with jquery?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to fetch the API data to a jquery variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request