# Getting 403 error when sending a POST request Angular

Tags: django, angular, post, jwt, token

I am getting status code 403 error when sending post requset to server in django, the server is runing on locallhost, in postman the post request is working, What is the reason of occuring error

My auth.service.ts file

```
getUser():Observable<any>{
const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt');

if(!token){
  return throwError('Unauthorized')
}

const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type':'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer' + token
});

return this.http.get<any>(this.apiUrl_User, {headers})
```

}

Backend part in django

```
class UserView(APIView):

def get(self,request):
    token = request.COOKIES.get('jwt')

    if not token:
        raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated')
    
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, 'secret',algorithms=['HS256'])
    except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
        raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated')
    
    user = User.objects.filter(id = payload['id']).first()
    serializer = UserSerializer(user)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

here is corsheaders looks like

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    "http://locallhost:4200",
    "127.0.0.1"
]
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    "DELETE",
    "GET",
    "OPTIONS",
    "PATCH",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
 )
 CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    "accept",
    "authorization",
    "content-type",
    "user-agent",
    "x-csrftoken",
    "x-requested-with",
 )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django CSRF check failing with an Ajax POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request)

Comment: This doesn't seem right: "token = request.COOKIES.get('jwt')" You're checking cookies for jwt while the front end reads it from localStorage and then sends it as a header.

Answer (score 0):

403 Forbidden Error means you don't have access to access this route. Which means this is configured from the backend whereas if you are sending the token check the place above the controller what role you are allowing the user to access this and check if the logging in users token contains that permission or not. For example role could effect it. Make sure to check the properties of the token as well. If its a jwt token make sure to go to jwt.io and then check for the permissions set for this token.

Over here

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer' + token
```

Make sure to add space after Bearer

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
```

Like this. because this can cause issues with some backends as well.